# The method attachToEdgeChrome() is undefined for the type InternetExplorerOptions using selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, selenium-edgedriver, selenium4

I want test the IE mode for Edge browser with Selenium. I found the solution on the MS site here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java

I am using the following code as given in the above link:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;

InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

I can get the error that the methods `"attachToEdgeChrome()"` and `"withEdgeExecutablePath()"` are not defined in the InternetExplorerOptions. Is there anything I am missing here?

**Note**: My selenium jar is selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ChangeLogs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f5dbc3584d18510a82ef91c3aac6221bb5940c54/java/CHANGELOG#L393) 0f ***Selenium v4.0.0.0-alpha-2***:

> - Add Chromium-based Edge support. This involves adding a new Chromium driver to  the tree too.

So ideally, the code block from the documentation [Use Internet Explorer Driver to automate IE mode in Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java) should have worked seamlessly.

However, as per best practices instead of using the *`alpha`* and *`beta`* releases, you should always prefer the ***GA*** releases to execute your tests and you can pickup anyone from the following options:

- ***Selenium v4.1.3***
- ***Selenium v4.1.2***
- ***Selenium v4.1.1***
- ***Selenium v4.1.0***
- ***Selenium v4.0.0***